# how to send hashtag character with my text in http request via telegram bot?

Tags: api, methods, bots, telegram, hashtag

I use this format to send text messages to a special group via my Bot in Telegram , but I don't know how to send hashtag character in my text ?

https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id

Answer (score 6):

Use [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

For example: `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=12345678&text=This%20is%20an%20%23hashtag`

Comment: How should we write searchable hashtag? when I send hashtag in my text before a phrase, the phrase is not clickable for instant search.

Comment: @Alireza your "phrase" must be a word without spaces or special chars (except for `_`) in it. Example: `#hello`, `#hello_world`, `#telegram`, `#telegramisthebest`.

Comment: It actually is. I use POST method and I have a uuid4 token that I want to enable it for instant search. but it doesn't activate. I should also say that I have set parse method to "Markdown". Does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Alireza you can convert your uuid4 in anything else, because it's impossible to enable it for instant search. The parse mode doesn't affect the hashtags mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php for your bot, you can use this in your script

```
 "https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=xxxxxxxx&text=".urlencode($text)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Percent Encoding
And Telegram Bot API...
please See Link below

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjS3PGiwK3zAhXCz4UKHX8NDYUQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fwrxck%2Fhashtag-bot&usg=AOvVaw2J7cqOS5IUY4VayySjRFw2